# Custom order (not alpha or numeric) of query results

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Is it possible to create a custom `ORDER BY` function in a google sheets `QUERY`?

In this scenario, I don't want the results to be alphabetical nor numeric, but rather a custom order based on a predefined category list that is actually in a separate tab from both the `QUERY` range as well as the formula itself.

I'm not really sure where to begin: Is this even possible?  Should the category list be moved to one of the other sheets? Does the category list need to be written into the formula?

Just looking for guidance at this point.

[My Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Za3a9d3hKJCMAxy72sIRH9L61wLwvBw02Fwj_9E_z-4/edit#gid=168249208&range=A5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({QUERY({Estimate!A2:H}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY({Estimate!A2:A}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0), 
 IF(LEN(A5:A), {A5:A, ROW(A5:A)}, ), 2, 0))}, 
 "where Col1 is not null 
  order by Col9", 0), 999^99, 8))
```

[image]